# In Jasmine, are there any differences between beforeAll() and let?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, ecmascript-6

I've tried thinking this through, reading SO questions and I've created a little test:

```
describe("let", () => {
  let x = 1;
  it("",function() {
    console.log(x + "<< it");
    console.log(y + "<< it");
  });
});

describe("beforeAll()", () => {
  let x;
  let y = 2;
  beforeAll(() => {
    x = 1;
  });
  it("",function() {
    console.log(x + "<< it");
    console.log(y + "<< it");
  });
});
```

Where the output is as follows:

```
LOG: '1<< it'
LOG: 'undefined<< it'
LOG: '1<< it'
LOG: '2<< it'
```

This implies to me that both beforeAll() and let are both scoped to the containing function and run before any of the contained `it`s are run. With `let` (and indeed `var`) my understanding of JavaScript scoping makes the results involving let expected.

This wouldn't happen in RSpec where `y` would be defined in the first test as describes are run outside of the `it`s. (This is the main reason I'm asking, I'd like to clean up unnecessary code if possible as `let` is cleaner rather than have an RSpec hangover lead to unneeded verbosity).

So are there any differences between `beforeAll()` and `let` that I'm not aware of (that flaws in my test / understanding might have obfuscated)?

Answer (score 1):

`beforeAll` callback has access to spec `this` and can be asynchronous.

If `this` context isn't used in specs, I would suggest to use `let`/`const` for constants and `beforeAll` for setup actions (that can be optionally paired with `afterAll`).